# facing issue with htpasswd in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am trying to develop http authentication in one of my wordpress site.

I have done below code for this.

in my .htaccess file at root folder.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /htpass_wordpress/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /htpass_wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

I have also created one more.htaccess file for my wp-admin folder.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /htpass_wordpress/wp-admin/.htpasswd
AuthName "My Private Area"
require valid-user
```

I have created one htpasswd file and put it in wp-admin( same directory where htaccess for wp-admin is stored).

I have stored my user name and base 64 encrypted password in that file.

Now When I access my wp-admin area, pop up appears to ask login.
I provide the username/pass and it allows me to access wp-admin. but then it gives me 500 server error.

does any one know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Show server log - there is more info about error.

Comment: this is in localhost and I have not configured logs in it. :)

Comment: And dont even know how to configure logs.!!!

Comment: Default log should be in /var/log/apache2/error.log or something like that

Comment: thanks pedro. It helped me out. :)